# Output from Select statement + suffix

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a SQL statement that returns a field, is there a way to at the end of that field to return a percentage sign at the end.

Example:

```
Select percentage from Customer WHERE percentage > 10;
```

Is there a way for the output instead of being

```
11
12
15
```

To be

```
11 % 
12 %
15 %
```

N.B It seems to be causing allot of confusion, but I am using Access 2010. Thanks

Comment: When you add the percentage sign, you will be converting from a numeric data type to a text data type, which may cause you a lot of problems if you arrach the query to a form. I suggest you do not add percentage signs to data, but to your output. In other words, this should be a presentation level issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
SELECT [percentage] & " %" AS Expr1 FROM [Customer] WHERE [percentage] > 10;
```

Comment: Will this work as a prefix to an output as well? - Edit: I can't accept the answer for 5 minutes. However, I see no reason why not to accept the answer when it did exactly what I wanted :-)

Comment: re: prefix - You mean `"some text " & [percentage] AS Expr2`? Yes, it will.

Comment: @GordThompson http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/110644/comment-regarding-accept-rate-removed

Answer (score 2):

```
Select convert(varchar,percentage) + ' %' from Customer WHERE percentage > 10;
```

That should do the trick for you.

Comment: That is not valid in Access: `Undefined function 'convert' in expression.`

Comment: Hi, I have just run your code and it gave me error in the field? Thanks for the quick reply :-)

Comment: apologies... I gave you the syntax for SQL Server and not Access. The answer below should have sorted you out.

Comment: As an aside, in Stackoverflow, SQL is a generic tag and you need to see the next tag along for the particular flavour required.

Answer (score 0):

```
Select percentage || '%' from Customer WHERE percentage > 10;
```

Comment: That is not valid syntax in Access.

Comment: As an aside, in Stackoverflow, SQL is a generic tag and you need to see the next tag along for the particular flavour required.